# Laravel How to append Ajax json in Select option

Tags: laravel

what is issue with my code, it returns empty drop down. i want drop down of nationality table, in teachers profile.

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="nation_id" id="nation_id">
     <input type="hidden" name="teacher_nation_id" id="teacher_nation_id" 
      value="{{ @$teacher->nation_id}}">
</select>
```

ajax code which returns empty dropdown: **Ajax:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $.get('nations-list', function(data) {
            let teacher_nation_id = $('#teacher_nation_id').val();
            let nations = $('#nation_id');
            nations.empty();

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                nations.append("<option value='"+ key +"'>" + value + "</option>");
            });

            nations.val(teacher_nation_id); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My **Controller:**

```
public function ajaxrequest(Request $request)
{

  $nations = Nation::all()->pluck('nation', 'id');

    return response()->json($nations);
}
```

Here is my route:
**Route:**

```
Route::get('nations-list','TeachersController@ajaxrequest');
```

Comment: Can you show me the result of data you are fetching through ajax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
<input type="hidden" name="teacher_nation_id" id="teacher_nation_id" 
  value="{{ @$teacher->nation_id}}">

<select class="form-control" name="nation_id" id="nation_id">
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="area" id="area">
</select>
```

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
$('#nation_id').click(function($){
    var tid = $('#teacher_nation_id').val();
    if(tid){
        $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           url:"{{url('/getNation)}}/"+tid,
           success:function(res)
           {    
                $('#nation_id').empty();
                $("#nation_id").append('<option>--Select Nation--</option>');
                if(res)
                {
                    $.each(res,function(key,value){
                        $('#nation_id').append($("<option/>", {
                           value: key,
                           text: value
                        }));
                    });
                }
           }

        });
    }
});
$('#nation_id).change(function(){
    var nid = $(this).val();
        if(nid){
        $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           url:"{{url('/getArea')}}/"+nid,
           success:function(res)
           {     
                $("#area").empty();
                $("#area").append('<option>--Select Area--</option>');
                if(res)
                {
                    $.each(res,function(key,value){
                        $('#area').append($("<option/>", {
                           value: key,
                           text: value
                        }));
                    });
                }
           }

        });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function getNation($id)
{
    $nations= DB::table("nations")
                ->where("teacher_nation_id",$id)
                ->pluck("nation","id")
                ->toArray();
    return response()->json($nations);    
}
public function getArea($id)
{
    $areas= DB::table("areas")
                ->where("nation_id",$id)
                ->pluck("area","id")
                ->toArray();
    return response()->json($areas);    
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/getNation/{id}','NationsController@getNation);
Route::get('/getArea/{id}','AriasController@getArea); 
//Here I assumes that You have different controller named AreasController you can gave name of your controller
```

Hope it will useful for you..
Good Luck...

Comment: Thankyou, can you please tell me how to load data when i select (select option) instead of on document ready.

Comment: sure.. so you need that whenever you select teacher from dropdown the nations should be load of that teacher in other dropdown.. right?

Comment: i have drop down of nation, and it should get nations from database only when i click on drop down of nation.

Comment: ok you can use on click event. so when you will click the dropdown then the ajax call get executed.. if that thing you want I can modify the answer.. should I?

Comment: yes please that would be grateful, can you please also tell me, if i want to get area dropdown too, what changes i will have to do in your code, please edit answer and i will mark as accepted answer, sorry for bothering you, Thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer. Feel free to contact me, if you have any doubts.. Its a pleasure that I can help you..